# Any reason why is my code duplicating the tokens im creating? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

What is happening is whenever I create a token it posts the previous token too

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sA5E.png)

This is the code below that I'm using to generate tokens.

```
tokenOpts = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".lower()

tkn = []

def GenToken():
    t1 = ''.join((choice(tokenOpts)) for x in range(5))
    t2 = ''.join((choice(tokenOpts)) for x in range(3))
    t3 = ''.join((choice(tokenOpts)) for x in range(7))
    t4 = ''.join((choice(tokenOpts)) for x in range(5))
    return f"{t1}-{t2}-{t3}-{t4}"

@bot.command()
async def createtoken(ctx, planDays=0):
    if ctx.message.author.id in config.OWNERS:
        with open(path, "r") as data: tokens = json.load(data)
        with open(path, "w") as output:
            #with open("temp", "w") as tk:
            for i in range(int(1)): 
                tok = GenToken()
                tkn.append(tok)
                tokens[0]['Unused'].append({"Days": planDays, "Level": "None", "Token": str(tok)})
            output.write(json.dumps(tokens, sort_keys=False, indent=4))
            o = '\n'.join(tkn)
            # tk.write(o)
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Verification",
                color= discord.Color.dark_theme()
            )
            embed.add_field(name="Token Status: Created <:white_check_mark:886940376127131689>", value=f"Token: `{o}`")
            embed.set_footer(text="YoursTruly.exe")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: why do you have `for i in range(int(1)): `. the for loop is useless the int cast is also useless. if it's only gonna happen once then remove the for loop and un indent the lines. and where is tkn defined?

Comment: @WasiMaster
oops, my bad, tkn is a table. I will place it inside the code, thank you for noticing.
Edit:
Just edited my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkn` is defined globally, so if you append another token, it will be stored even after the method had finished.
So every time the method is called, `tkn` is getting one entry longer.

Just move the declaration of `tkn` inside the function. Or don't use it all, just use `tok` instead of `o` in the embed. It should work also.